# Does std::move invalidate a raw pointer obtained from unique_ptr::get()?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Suppose I have a unique pointer and I take a copy of its raw pointer like this:

```
auto t = std::make_unique<int>(67);
auto m = t.get();
auto d = std::move(t);
std::cout << *m;
```

I know `m` will be valid until `t` is modified or destroyed.

But when I move ownership from `t`, `m` is still valid.

Could someone help me understand what happens here, and what the standard says about this?

Comment: What you know is incorrect.  `m` will be valid until the pointer is destroyed.  The pointer is owned by `t`, then owned by `d`, but it is not destroyed when `t` moves ownership to `d`.

Comment: Moving a `unique_ptr` is like selling a house - there is a new owner, but the house stays put.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`m` is a raw pointer to the integer owned by `t`. `auto d = std::move(t);` transfers ownership to a new smart pointer `d`. The internal raw pointer of `d` gets set to the address of your resource and the raw pointer of `t` gets set to a null pointer.

The integer that is now owned by `d` is still at the exact same location as before. That is why your raw pointer `m` that you got from `t` to that address is still valid after the move to `d`.

At this point `t` has nothing to do with your integer any more; it's just a `std::unique_ptr<int>` that is currently not assigned. Your raw pointer `m` will remain valid **until the currently owning unique pointer actually deletes it**, for example because it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

Transferring the ownership of the integer between `std::unique<int>` objects, from `t` to `d`, does not affect `m` because `m` doesn't own the integer. `m` is a raw pointer (i.e., `int *`), it never participates in the ownership of the integer.

If `m` doesn't outlive the object that owns the integer – which is `d` by the end of your snippet – there can't be any issue.